# Disable code first migrations per user

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

We're a team of 4 developers and have been developing a product using Code First Migrations for about 21 months.  We've had countless issues and headaches using this code first migrations (as we all make db changes and checkins simultaneously) and are currently considering our alternatives.  We are currently setting up TeamCity as our build server so that when we check in the solution is automatically built and if everything is good the code is automatically pushed out to a preview server.

We were going to try a situation where we don't check in migrations, just the model changes, and we all build the migrations locally, so we avoid the headache of merging/getting the order out of sync.  Then when we're finished our development on a certain package of work we'll create one migration that we can effectively run on live environments.  What we were wondering is if there's anyway to turn off/disable code first migrations on some sort of config so that we can develop using code first migrations but have TeamCity successfully build the project and then manually update the database without using migrations?

I've read that you can disable migrations by deleting the migrations folder that was originally created when migrations were enabled and delete the MigrationHistory table but we would still want this locally, however, we would want TeamCity to ignore the migrations aspect whilst we're still developing.  Only when we completed the package of work would we want to enable the migrations again so the db can be updated and the code rolled out to our preview server.

I hope this makes sense and if anybody has any experience of life after code first migrations please tell all!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Automatic execution of migrations is configured in the migrations Configuration class (automatically generated when you first enable migrations):

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MigrationsContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
//...
}
```